# How to change button active color in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I have this output

Button Not Click
[image]

Button Hover
[image]

Button Click (Here's My Problem)
[image]

How can I change that active button color?

I have this code:

```css
/**BTN Primary**/
.btn{
    border-radius:1px;
}

.btn-primary{
    background-color: rgb(114, 96, 153);
    border-color:rgb(114, 96, 153);
}

.btn-primary:hover{
    background-color: rgb(94, 79, 126);
    border-color:rgb(94, 79, 126);
}

.btn-primary:focus{
    background-color: rgb(94, 79, 126);
    border-color:rgb(94, 79, 126);
}

.btn-primary:active{
    background-color: rgb(94, 79, 126);
    border-color:rgb(94, 79, 126);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(114, 96, 153, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
/**BTN Primary**/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to overwrite `.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{`

inspect the element and in the dev tool, click on `toggle pseudo class` then check `active` to see what rules are applied when the button is active, you'll see if your rules are overwritten or what you have to overwrite.

[image]

couldn't get it to work in the snippet , here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/takius/h9sj80kx/14/

**EDIT :** ( based on the comment )

to change the blue shadow, it's in : `.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):focus{`

updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/takius/h9sj80kx/32/

Comment: You got it. Thank you sir!

Comment: last question sir. box-shadow wont change. How to change it?

Comment: .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{
    background-color: rgb(94, 79, 126);
    border-color:rgb(94, 79, 126);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(114, 96, 153, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}

Comment: you're welcome, i updated the answer for the shadow :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `webpack` or similar compiler to get `css` from bootstrap source code

you can do it like so in your `my.scss` file

```
$blue:    rgb(114, 96, 153);
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```